# Bind variables in case statement in MonetDB

Tags: pentaho, bind-variables, monetdb

I seem to have come across a strange restriction in using bind variables in MonetDB. If i use bind variables in the normal way by saying where field=${var} then it works. But not in this case:

Here is a sample:

```
select case when ${Brand} = 'All'
```

And here is the error:

```
EXEC: wrong type for argument 1 of prepared statement: char, expected char
```

Using the latest version of the jdbc driver (2.9) via Pentaho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting to char doesnt work either.

However casting both sides to Varchar does work i.e.:

```
cast(${Brand} as varchar(100)) = cast('All' as varchar(100))
```

So I guess char's are just a bit funky in MonetDB